# Simple Service worker notification click not working

Tags: service-worker

I'm trying to get notification click events from notifications in Chrome (Windows 10). When the service activates, it will automatically show a notification message with two buttons on it. Clicking either button should cause the notification click handler to fire, but it doesn't.

Here's a simple example.

## CLIENT.JS:

```
self.addEventListener('install', function (event) {
    console.log(">>> installing client service worker");
    self.skipWaiting();
});

self.addEventListener('activate', function (event) {
    console.log('>>> client service activated');
    showNotificationMessage("xxx", "yyy", "123");
});

self.addEventListener('notificationclick', function (event) {
    console.log('>>> On notification click: ', event.notification.tag);
});

function showNotificationMessage(messageTitle, bodyMessage, data) {
    registration.showNotification(messageTitle, {
        actions: [{ action: "a", title: "action a" }, { action: "b", title: "action b", }],
        body: bodyMessage,
        requireInteraction: true,
        renotify: true,
        tag: 'test',
        data: data
    }).then(console.log('>>> notification was successful')).catch(function (error) {
        console.log(">>> showNotification error: " + error);
    });
}
```

## CLIENT.HTML

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
// Register service worker
navigator.serviceWorker.register('Client.js').then(function (reg) {
console.log("SW registration succeeded. Scope is " + reg.scope);
}).catch(function (err) {
console.error("SW registration failed with error " + err);
});
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
When this page loads, a notification should be displayed from the service worker. Clicking the action buttons should cause a notification click event in the service worker, but it doesn't.
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: is any of the console log's working from the client.js service worker scripts?

Comment: Yes, console.log works except inside of notificationclick handler - which never fires. It seems as the though putting a event.waitUntil  in the notificationclick handler makes things work. Does that make any sense?

Comment: maybe you need to registrate the notification on `self`. like `self.registration.showNotification(...`. but i'm just guessing. or yes, maybe your event binding fires to early..